# RemoteViewsService not getting called

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-widget, android-service

Please note that the code works perfectly until I upgrade the widget/app to a newer version. The new version does not change anything to cause this issue.

On attempting to upgrade the widget I get following in logcat and UI doesn't update as the *RemoteViewsService* is not getting executed anymore.

```
E/AbstractRemotePanelView: composeCocktailWithBundle:  bundle:null
E/RemoteViews: Cannot setRemoteViewsAdapter on a view which is not an AbsListView or AdapterViewAnimator (id: 2131690005)
E/RemoteViews: Cannot setPendingIntentTemplate on a view which is notan AdapterView (id: 2131690005)
```

In my opinion the widget is just not going through a fresh/clean initialization on upgrading the app and that messes up things. Any suggestions/tips on how to fix it?